# Javascript form validation onsubmit not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I wrote a validation function in Javascript to check that my passwords match.

HTML

```
<form action="/anotherPage" onsubmit="return validate()" method="POST">
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="password" name="password2"/>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
  function validate() {
      var ok = true;
      var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
      var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
      if (password != password2) {
          alert("Passwords Do not match");
          document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
          document.getElementById("password2").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
          ok = false;
      }
      else {
          alert("Passwords Match!!!");
      }
      return ok;
  }
</script>
```

In console it says form submitted, but I want to validate before form is submitted.But my validation function is never reached. How do I fix this?

Comment: Errors in console?

Comment: In console it says form submitted, but I want to validate before form is submitted. The validation function is never reached.

Comment: In your html you wrote `<input type="password" name="password"/>` and in your js `document.getElementById("password")`. You should add id attribute to the two password elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using getElementById - but you don't have input fields with such IDs. Add `id="password"` and `id="password2"` to input fields - and magic will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `event.preventDefault` to prevent default form submit

```
function validate(event) {
event.preventDefault();
      //Rest of code
      return ok;
  }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vhnm0kzy/)

Answer (score 0):

You missed to define the id of your input :

```
<form action="/anotherPage" onsubmit="return validate()" method="POST">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2"/>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using jQuery But first you have to give your `input` an `id`

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
<input type="password" id="password2" name="password2"/>
// then the jQuery
pass = $('#password').val();
pass2 = $('#password2').val();
if(pass == pass2){
    alert('good');
} else {
    alert('bad');
}
```

Comment: `pass = $('[name="password"]')` and `pass2 = $('[name="password2"]')` would work, but OP did not assign `id`s